# Extending accelerated .Net class using the original constructors

Tags: powershell, class, extend

Inspired by theses questions:

- [Get a specific octet from the string representation of an IPv4
  address](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63710588/1701026)
- [Powershell - Checking IP Address range based on CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62609183/1701026)

I am trying to extend the [`IPAddress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress?view=netcore-3.1) class with an `ToBigInt()` method in PowerShell (if even possible) to be able to easily compare (IPv4 *and* IPv6) addresses using comparison operations along with `-lt` and `-gt`. E.g.:

```
([IPAddress]'2001:db8::8a2e:370:7334').ToBigInt() -lt ([IPAddress]'2001:db8::8a2e:370:7335').ToBigInt()
```

My first attempt:

```
class IPAddress : System.Net.IPAddress {
    [Void]ToBigInt() {
        $BigInt = [BigInt]0
        foreach ($Byte in $This.GetAddressBytes()) {
            $BigInt = ($BigInt -shl 8) + $Byte
        }
        $BigInt
    }
}
```

Causes an error:

> ```
> Line |
>    1 |  class IPAddress : System.Net.IPAddress {
>      |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>      | Base class 'IPAddress' does not contain a parameterless constructor.
> ```

So apparently, I need to add the (`[IPAddress]::new`) constructors to the sub class:

```
class IPAddress : System.Net.IPAddress {
    IPAddress ([long]$NewAddress) : base($NewAddress) { }
    IPAddress ([byte[]]$Address, [long]$ScopeId) : base($Address, $ScopeID) { }
    IPAddress ([System.ReadOnlySpan[byte]]$Address, [long]$ScopeId) : base($Address, $ScopeID) { }
    IPAddress ([byte[]]$Address) : base($Address) { }
    IPAddress ([System.ReadOnlySpan[byte]]$Address) : base($Address) { }
    
    [Void]ToBigInt() {
        $BigInt = [BigInt]0
        foreach ($Byte in $This.GetAddressBytes()) {
            $BigInt = ($BigInt -shl 8) + $Byte
        }
        $BigInt
    }
}
```

Now, the class defintion is accepted but when I try to create an `IPAddress`, like:

```
[IPAddress]'172.13.23.34'
```

I get a new error:

> ```
> OperationStopped: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Net.IPAddress' to type 'IPAddress'.
> ```

How can I resolve this casting error?

Comment: This is not how you'd usually extend things in PowerShell, and inheritance is supported for other scenarios. Try [`Add-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-member#example-4--add-a-script-method-to-a-fileinfo-object) instead.

Comment: @Jeroen, Correct me if I am wrong, but using `Add-Member` isn't exactly the same because that attaches the methods to an instance of the class (not on the class itself). Besides, I am actually able to do this on a (parameterless) `[DataTable]` class, see: [How to set the default output of a PowerShell class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60487695/1701026).

Comment: Yes, `Add-Member` works on instances. Not generally a problem since you're working with instances in any given script too (or else you can stream things through custom cmdlets). PowerShell has added classes and inheritance now, but there remain rough edges because this feature is mainly intended for DSC, not to provide extensions to system classes. I have no idea where the conversion from `String` to `System.Net.IPAddress` is defined in PS, but I suspect that's what you're getting in combination with another conversion. Try defining a constructor on your class that takes a `String`.

Comment: @Jeroen, thanks for the comments. I have tried adding constructors like `IPAddress ([string]$Address) : base($Bytes) { $Bytes = [Byte[]]$Address.Split('.') }` and  `IPAddress ([System.Net.IPAddress]$Address) : base($Bytes) { $Bytes = $Address.GetAddressBytes() }` but that didn't help. I guess that I am really at (/over) the edge of what is supposed to work from PowerShell. I have little C# knowledge and don't understand how PowerShell manages to cast a `[string]` to a `[IPAddress]` type with doesn't have a `[string]` constructor. E.g. how does it know how to split the string?

Comment: Apparently it has a whole [battery or heuristics](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/understanding-powershells-type-conversion-magic/) it uses to find the approach, of which a custom `PSTypeConverter` is the ultimate fallback. In this case it should be deferring to `IPAddress::Parse`.